# Different colors corresponding to each chart within layered chart?

Tags: python, altair

To make a chart similar in appearance to the [Simple Stacked Area Chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_stacked_area_chart.html) provided in the Altair Docs, I've tried making a layered
area chart which encodes different colors for the data from each of the constituent charts.

Here is a snippet of the pandas dataframe being used to generate the chart:

```
df.head():
```

```
    date        currently_active total_recovered total_cases
0   2020-01-27     1               0               1
1   2020-01-28     1               0               1
2   2020-01-29     1               0               1
3   2020-01-30     1               0               1
4   2020-01-31     1               0               1
```

```
df.dtypes:
```

```
date                datetime64[ns]
currently_active             int64
total_recovered              int64
total_cases                  int64
dtype: object
```

And here is the code I've used to attempt to plot the layered area chart:

```
area = alt.Chart(df).configure_area(color='blue').mark_area(opacity=0.5).encode(
    x='monthdate(date):T',
    y='total_cases:Q'
)

area2 = alt.Chart(df).configure_area(color='red').mark_area(opacity=0.5).encode(
    x='monthdate(date):T',
    y='currently_active:Q'
)

area + area2
```

The above returns this:

```
'ValueError: Objects with "config" attribute cannot be used within LayerChart. Consider defining the config attribute in the LayerChart object instead.'
```

Thanks! Please let me know how I can further clarify the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As written, there is not enough information to answer your question well. You will be much more likely to get a useful answer to your chart if you include a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you've tried. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: @jakevdp Thank you for the helpful information and nice welcome. I edited the original question--hopefully it's provided some clarity on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `configure` property within plots that you are layering. You would need to set the config on the final layered plot instead, but in your case you want to apply different colors to each of the charts, which can more easily be achieved by using `color` inside `mark_area`, as below:

```
area = alt.Chart(df).mark_area(opacity=0.5, color='blue').encode(
    x='monthdate(date):T',
    y='total_cases:Q'
)

area2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_area(opacity=0.5, color='red').encode(
    x='monthdate(date):T',
    y='currently_active:Q'
)

area + area2
```